# Unable to Load external CSS in JSP page

Tags: css, jsp

I am trying to loading an external css page in my jsp page but the usual way of doing it doesnt help , Is there anything that am missing out ?

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">


 <title>Login Page</title>
<head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
</head>
```

Comment: could you try passing the Url for style.css on browser and see if it comes up , i think the realtive path is not correct , is the style sheet in the same directory as of the JSP file

Comment: yes css it is in the same directory

Comment: were you able to open the CSS with browser ?

Comment: are u using any URL pattern(like we use for servlets) for the JSP page?If so then you need to specify the absolute path of external resources being used in page(images, css , js files ....)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `href` in your link element specifes a URL-relative path that will only work if the css file is in the same folder as the `JSP` and if the `JSP` is directly addressed.

Since you have mentioned that `css` is in the same directory as `JSP`. Check how you are addressing JSP.

You need either to insert the context path to your webapp (e.g. /webapp/styles.css) or use a relative path or use the HTML `<base>` tag. It denotes the base URL of all relative URL's used in the final HTML output.

```
<head>
    <base href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
</head>
```